# Mounting /dev/dvd /media on VirtualBox

Tags: command-line, mount, scientific-linux

I have installed Scientific Linux on VirtualBox and I am trying to follow some exercises on a book I picked up. The first thing I need to do is:

```
mount /dev/dvd /media
```

But when I do that, I get

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

What I would like to do is mount the virtual DVD where I see that the DVD in the Options of VirtualBox has all the necessary files I need, but it won't let me mount. Can anyone tell me if something has been mis-configured or where I can check to see if it has been?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /dev/dvd`?

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3      Aug 9 08:32 /dev/dvd -> sr0`

Comment: I want to make sure I understand everything: 1) You have a VM install of Scientific Linux. 2) You are trying to mount a dvd inside of the VM. 3) You already added the device to the storage options of the VM in Virtual Box.

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Just in the off change, is there a `/dev/sr1`?

Comment: @SailorCire, there is a `dev/sr1`

Comment: `mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media`

Comment: Thanks I did that after I realized the root cause of the problem. It wasn't just listing the mount type that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have realized that the reason why `/dev/dvd` was not being read was because of a setting that I had turned off on VirtualBox. I experimented a little bit and was able to mount the drive after that point.

The setting I had to turn on was the .iso file found in Devices, DVD/CD in VirtualBox. I turned it off earlier because it kept taking me to the installation process.

Comment: Can you specify what setting that was?

Comment: I had to check off the .iso file found in Devices, DVD/CD in VirtualBox. I shut it off because it kept taking me to the installation process.

Comment: Ok. I would be better to add this to your answer. If you prefer, I can do this. In any case, I have upvoted.

Comment: Please do :), i have no access to a PC at the moment.

Comment: Done. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add  `-t FILESYSTEMTYPE`, with FILESYSTEMTYPE being auto, ext4, ntfs or any other valid system type. Which gives you `mount /dev/dvd /media -t auto`, by example.

Comment: I have tried as suggested and got `mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0`

Answer (score -1):

I believe VirtualBox has an option to directly enable mounting of your physical DVD. Directly mounting won't work, because here Virtual Box needs to emulate ur DVD.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. I was not trying to mount my physical DVD drive. I needed to mount the virtual DVD drive. When I checked off the DVD/CD devices that allowed me to mount the drive and locate the .iso file I needed to use.